# Adding new objects to an NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a custom class named `Profile` and a `NSMutableArray` which I add the profile objects in case I need to go back and forth in an iteration.

The code is this:

```
@try {
    currentProfile = (Profile *) [cache objectAtIndex:(int)currentPosition-1];
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    Profile *cached = [[Profile alloc] init];
    [cached loadProfile:currentPosition orUsingUsername:nil appSource:source];
    cached.position = NULL;
    [cache addObject:cached];
    currentProfile = cached;
    [cached release];
}

//And the "log" i use to show the error
Profile *temp;
for (int i=0; i<[cache count]; i++) {

    temp = (Profile *) [cache objectAtIndex:(int)currentPosition-1];
    NSLog(@"%@ - %d e %d", temp.name, temp.position, temp.realId);
}
[temp release];
```

The NSLog is returning me lenght of cache times with the same object. I.E.
for len = 1:
first  - 1 e 1

for len = 2:
second  - 2 e 2
second  - 2 e 2

for len = 3:
third - 3 e 3
third - 3 e 3
third - 3 e 3

and so on...
And what I need is:
for len = 3:
first - 1 e 1
second - 2 e 2
third - 3 e 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use variable `i` inside the loop, instead of `currentPosition`

```
for (int i=0; i<[cache count]; i++) {
    temp = (Profile *) [cache objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"%@ - %d e %d", temp.name, temp.position, temp.realId);
}
```

Otherwise, you're always retrieving the same object.

You may also want to consider 'for each' loop instead of a simple 'for'. Just for the sake of simplicity.

```
for (Profile *temp in cache) {
  NSLog(@"%@ - %d e %d", temp.name, temp.position, temp.realId);
}
```

Comment: ^^ you answered faster, no need for 2 times the same post so deleting mine

Comment: @Jason Check out [stackapps](http://stackapps.com/), they have some useful notification utilities :)

Comment: God, thank you!! That was fast and very useful. And I feel stupid =(